# Fastest coin movement

Tags: java, puzzle

I have a puzzle where I need to reduce a number to zero by removing 17 each with some conditions. Below is the puzzle for your understanding.

Starting with 138 coins find the least number of moves to reach exactly 0 coins.  With each move you can either (a) discard 17 coins, (b) discard 1 coins or (c) discard half your coins (but only if you currently have an even number of coins).  Write a program that tests all possible combination of moves and prints the number of moves required by the fastest move combination.

I found the fastest movement using the below code. Now , I need to find out the other possible movements but I'm stuck with it. Could anybody help here?

```
package com.infy.cis.test;

public class CoinMovementPuzzle {

    static int times=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        numDiv(138,2,17,1);

    }
    public static void numDiv(int a, int b,int c,int d) {

        if(a!=0)
        {
            int remainder=a%b;;
            if(remainder==0 && a>=2)
            {
                evenNumber(a,b);
            }
            else if(remainder!=0 && a>=17)
            {
                oddNumber17(a,c);
            }
            else
            {
                oddNumber1(a,d);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("FINAL"+times);
        }
    private static void oddNumber1(int a,int d) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a=a-d;
        times=times+1;
        System.out.println("odd number::"+a+"::"+times);
        numDiv(a, 2,17,1);

    }
    private static void oddNumber17(int a,int c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //int rem;
        int rem=a%c;
        a/=c;
        times=times+a;

        System.out.println("odd number::"+a+"::"+times);
        numDiv(rem, 2,17,1);

    }
    private static void evenNumber(int a,int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a/=2;
        times=times+1;
        //System.out.println(a/=b);
        //remainder=a%b;
        System.out.println("Value of a"+a);
        System.out.println("even number::"+a+"::"+times);
        numDiv(a, 2,17,1);


    }
}
```

Comment: Start with formatting your code, then please tell us where exactly you are stuck and what you tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780471/java-program-for-fastest-coin-move-combination

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).  Create a tree where the first move is half, 17, and 1.  This creates 3 nodes.  For each of the nodes, create new nodes with the legal moves.  When you've created all the nodes (in other words, when all of your child nodes are zero), then you've created a tree with all of the combinations of moves.

Comment: Are you sure your algorithm finds the fastest movement? I see that running the code gives you a results of 6 moves as the quickest path. But the following series of moves . . . Start with 138, divide by 2 (69), minus one (68), divide by 2 (34), divide by 2 or minus 17 (17), minus 17 (0) . . . is only 5 moves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about solving a mathematical problem, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to a change-making problem. If you want to find the method with the minimum number of moves, a dynamic programming approach would work. You set up an array `a[i]`, `i=0..138` and build from smallest to largest. Start with `a[0]=0`. The number you store in `a[i]` is the `min(a[i-1]+1, a[i-17]+1, a[i/2]+1 (if i even))`. Work your way up to `a[138]`. Then to find the actual sequence of moves, figure out which of `a[138-1]`, `a[138-17]`, `a[138/2]` is less than `a[138]` and repeat until you hit `0`.

```
a[0] = 0
for i = 1 to 138
  if (i<17) 
    if (i odd)
      a[i] = a[i-1]+1
    else // i even
      a[i] = min(a[i-1]+1, a[i/2]+1)
   else // i >= 17
     if (i odd)
       a[i] = min(a[i-1]+1, a[i-17]+1)
     else // i even
       a[i] = min(a[i-1]+1, a[i-17]+1, a[i/2]+1)
   // end if
// a[138] now contains the minimum number of moves 
// find the actual sequence by working backwards
i = 138
while (i>0)
  if a[i-1] < a[i]
    print -1
    i = i-1
  else if a[i-17] < a[i]
    print -17
    i = i-17
  else if a[i/2] < a[i]
    print /2
    i = i/2
  else 
    // shouldn't end up here
    print error
```

This is the the best way to find the maximum, in my opinion, but it doesn't answer your question in that it doesn't find all answers and then pick the best.

You might be able to find a solution that uses less memory for bigger questions.

If you want to find the minimum sequence the hard, slow way you can use recursion something like this:

```
sequenceOfMoves(string sequenceSoFar, int targetNumber)
  if targetNumber is 0, print sequenceSoFar // done
  if targetNumber > 0 sequenceOfMoves(sequenceSoFar + "-1", targetNumber-1)
  if targetNumber > 16 sequenceOfMoves(sequenceSoFar + "-17", targetNumber-17)
  if targetNumber is even sequenceOfMoves(sequenceSoFar + "/2", targetNumber/2)
```

Your initial call should be to `sequenceOfMoves("", 138)`

To answer the question, you need to store the sequences instead of printing them, then when the recursion is finished, search through your store for the shortest sequence of moves. Print them all, flagging the shortest as the winner.

Comment: Hi Edward, Could you please elabrate on the array part. Couldn't get an idea. Probably a small piece of code would help. Thanks..

Comment: I sketched the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Edward :). It helped a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This solution will print out the best (but not all) move in reverse order:
It works by using a breadth-first search algorithm by trying out all possible combinations and choosing the optimal ones at each stage.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {


    List<String> getMinMoves(int amount){

        if (amount <= 0){
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        int numMovesSubtractingSeventeen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        List<String> movesSubtractingSeventeen = null;
        if (amount >= 17){
            movesSubtractingSeventeen = getMinMoves(amount - 17);
            numMovesSubtractingSeventeen = 1 + movesSubtractingSeventeen.size();
        }

        List<String> movesSubtractingOne = getMinMoves(amount - 1);
        int numMovesSubtractingOne = 1 + movesSubtractingOne.size();

        List<String> movesDividingByTwo = null;
        int numMovesDivideByTwo = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if (amount % 2 == 0) {
            movesDividingByTwo = getMinMoves(amount/2);
            numMovesDivideByTwo = 1 + movesDividingByTwo.size();
        }

        if (numMovesSubtractingSeventeen < numMovesSubtractingOne){
            if (numMovesSubtractingSeventeen < numMovesDivideByTwo){
                movesSubtractingSeventeen.add("Subtract 17 from " + amount);
                return movesSubtractingSeventeen;

            } else {
                movesDividingByTwo.add("Divide " + amount + " by 2");
                return movesDividingByTwo;
            }
        } else {
            if (numMovesSubtractingOne < numMovesDivideByTwo) {
                movesSubtractingOne.add("Subtract 1 from " + amount);
                return movesSubtractingOne;
            }
            else {
                movesDividingByTwo.add("Divide " + amount + " by 2");
                return movesDividingByTwo;
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        List<String> moves = main.getMinMoves(138);
        System.out.println("Min number of moves: " + moves.size());
        for (String move : moves){
            System.out.println(move);
        }
    }

}
```

You can modify the code to return a set of Lists in cases where more than one solution is optimal.